# Getting ScriptManager's ServiceReference generated JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asmx, asp.net-4.0, scriptmanager

When upgrading an ASP.NET 4 (3.5 rendering) WebForms application to MVC 3, how can I get the same JavaScript generated by `ScriptManager` for a `ServiceReference` of an ASMX file?

I have an ASMX web service file that is used extensively via the JavaScript `ScriptManager` generates for it. The existing code needs to continue to work but you can't use `ScriptManager` in an MVC view. Is there a way to have the JavaScript code automatically generated in ASP.NET MVC?

Here is how I have it in my `Default.aspx` WebForm page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/WebService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `WebService.asmx/js` to the page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/WebService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note the trailing `/js` in `/WebService.asmx/js`.

Appending `/js` to the path of the `.asmx` file gives you the Javascript for your webservice. Likewise, appending `/jsdebug` gives you the verbose Javascript for debugging purposes.